# using jquery, lightbox and prototype together what exactly to do

Tags: jquery

when I put the following link below my page disappear leaving the bgcolor alone I include JQuery.noConflict because my slider and the lightbox are not working together and I was told that I will replace $ with jQuery on which of the script lightbox, prototype or jquery I do know and am I to replace "someid" too with what exactly please I am newbie in this how can I fix this I will like it if the solve provided are edited on the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
JQuery.noConflict();
JQuery(document).ready(function(){
JQuery("div").hide();
});

$('someid').style.display = 'none'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.5.js/"></script>
```

Comment: You should probably rethink whether or not you really NEED all those different libraries at once. You're downloading a lot of extra code that way.

Answer (score 1):

Js include order should

```
// jquery shold include first
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```